# Clean OpenGL support on MacOS X with multiple monitor fullscreen

Tags: macos, opengl, fullscreen, glut

I'm working on an OpenGL based application. I've been using GLUT for setting up the screen, but have encountered a problem.

When attaching a second monitor I would like to setup another window with another viewport, but using glut I can only setup one fullscreenview, that spans both monitors.

My question is, How do I setup two fullscreen windows under MacOSX, what do I need to use? It looks like this is not posible under GLUT, do I need to use X11 or can I use some more native framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an NSWindow with either an NSOpenGLView or a NSView with a manually-associated NSOpenGLContext as its content view.  Here's [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html) with example code.  In that example, it uses `[NSScreen mainScreen]`.  You can examine the array returned by `[NSScreen screens]` and pick a different screen.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this using c or c++? Without getting my hands dirty with Objective-C?

Comment: @MartinKristiansen: Unfortunately no.